# How to convert DataFrame in spark to HadoopRDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-dynamodb

I like to write dataframe in spark to dynamodb.
So I am using `rdd.saveAsHadoopDataset(JobConf)`.But the rdd type is mismatch.It needs the rdd of type hadoopRDD.So I like to convert the dataframe to rdd.I had used `df.rdd` which gives me rdd but not of hadoopRDD. I am using spark-scala API.If is there any better way of writing Dataframe to Dyanmodb from spark that will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to convert your RDD.

Because the Hadoop API structured around key-value pairs, Spark automatically wraps the PairRDDFunctions (which adds additional functionality) around RDDs where the data is stored in `Tuple2` objects. So you only need to put your data into an `RDD[(T,V)]`, then you'll have `saveAsHadoopDataset` method available.

Here is an example:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf
val tupleRDD : RDD[(Int, Int)] = sc.parallelize(Array((1,2), (3,4), (5,6)))
val jobConf = new JobConf()
```

Set whatever needs setting.

```
tupleRDD.saveAsHadoopDataset(jobConf)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.Do you have any example for spark-Scala for above. Actually I am newbie in spark so it will be helpful.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for writing dataframe from spark-scala to dyanmodb. Then following might be helpful.

```
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Item
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.DynamoDB

var json_arr=df.toJSON.collect() //Convert dataframe to json array
val table = dynamoDB.getTable("table_name") //dynamoDB is connection to dynamodb
for (element <- json_arr) {
      val item = Item.fromJSON(element)
      table.putItem(item)
    }
```

Comment: How was dynamoDB instantiated?